# Magic Leap Unity3d shared assets exceeds file size limit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build, assets, magic-leap

I was trying to upload my build for submission to Magic World, but size of shred assets generated with unity exceeds the limits.
Any tips on how to influence the way how unity divides assets to packages those packages ?
Thanks !

[image: Error]

Comment: apparently you are packing a lot of big data resources into your app? Like meshes etc? You should rather host them somewhere on a server and import them on runtime

Comment: Yes I have 50 meshes that weights around 1.6GB combined. I don't want to stream them - to make sure UX is good and people don't need to wait to see them.

Comment: well than you will have to reduce the mesh size of your models.

Comment: That's impossible as well - they're already optimised pretty heavily.

Comment: Then you will need to stream at least some of them

Comment: Any other workaround ? 
If nothing will work - I'll need to build native app instead of using unity..

Comment: well but apparently the app is simply to huge for ML .. not really a Unity issue I guess

Comment: Use another hoster?

Comment: I believe the problem is how unity manages their resources - I hoped it's possible to just change how I want app to be built: to change from 1 huge shared asset, to 10 let's say.

Comment: @BugFinder what do you mean by hoster ?

Comment: You can use check [AssetBundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html)

Comment: @AdamRoszyk dont put it on magic world, put it on a website you own or whatever that can tollerate the size limits

Comment: @derHugo Thanks, I'll try to that. BugFinder releasing through World is super important for us.

Comment: You could give it a shot and put them instead in the [Resources](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html) and load and unload the assets at runtime

Comment: @AdamRoszyk I would like to repeat you can use [AssetBundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) which compress your data by converting it to binary and you can load it any time you want. You can check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGULjJV7Kh0) explaining what it is.

Comment: @AliKanat  I'll check it out !